# Serialize flatbuffer to c++ string

Tags: c++, flatbuffers

In Protobuf I have method SerializeAsString (SerializeToString).
How to serialize to string in fbs?
Somehow I can't find this anywhere.

Comment: What makes you think there is such functionality in flatbuffers?

Comment: What are you talking about? [The tutorial](https://google.github.io/flatbuffers/flatbuffers_guide_tutorial.html) Clearly shows how to get a memory buffer out of a builder.

Comment: @Botje out of builder, yes. But I have builder only when I am sending buffer. I have no builder when I am parsing it.

Comment: If you already have a serialized buffer, why do you need to convert it to string as well? Anyway, I could find [this](https://google.github.io/flatbuffers/flatbuffers_guide_use_cpp.html#autotoc_md47) in under ten minutes.

Comment: @Botje omg, so cringe. I already used id, but absolutely forgot. I also was trying to grep by word 'string' on that page, don't know what has gone wrong. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

In comments Botje answered this question - use [mini reflection](https://google.github.io/flatbuffers/flatbuffers_guide_use_cpp.html#autotoc_md47)

```
auto s = flatbuffers::FlatBufferToString(flatbuf, MonsterTypeTable());
```

Comment: That converts an already serialized FlatBuffer to JSON, which I don't think what is being asked. I'm guessing they just want the memory buffer to be copied to a std::string, which is what the ProtoBuf version does

Comment: Yep, actually this is my question. I forgot to return there after realising, that FlatBufferToString is just for debug. I need exactly what Proto does.

Comment: In that case you need something along the lines of `std::string((const char *)fbb.GetBufferPointer(), fbb.GetSize())`. That string will then contain the binary representation, not text. This is a copy, so even better of course if you could convince whoever receives the string to instead take a pointer + size.